# Combination or Permutation

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am searching for the number of uniques ways to paint an icosahedron. However, my understanding of mathematics is quite limited in the field of combination and permutation. I have searched through many pages in google and herein but found myself unable to translate simple terms such as "repitition" to fit my question. I would be thankful for hints which help me in solving this question.

I have five silver balls and eight golden balls, and have to arrange them in icosahedral shape wherein the thirteenth position is in the centre.

[image]

In the first step I would like to calculate how many possible ways there are to arrange silver and golden balls over these thirteen positions. If I am correct, the answer is 91. I assumed it to by combinatorial problem with repition (is that right?). $$x = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!} = \frac{(13+2-1)!}{2!(13-1)!} = 91$$ where $n$ is the number of things to choose from, and we choose $r$ of them.

Now I would like to know how unique ways there are. If I compare two possibilities and I am able to show that they are identical simply by rotating the icosahedral arrangement, I would like to discard one of these. How can I implement this into calculations? ...

Please note, that this is not homework. This is an actual question I ask myself.

Comment: If I have understood your problem correctly, I think the answer to the first part should be $C(13,5)=1287$.  This is if you think of the arrangement of silver and gold balls as being fixed in space.  If you want to discount arrangements which are "equivalent by rotation" it is a more intricate problem, but if you Google "burnside orbit counting examples" or maybe "burnside orbit counting icosahedron" you should find something helpful.

Comment: Please excuse me, I was in such a hurry that I did not reply here to you. Thank you very much! The term "Burnside" helped me a lot. This helped me further in understanding (for everyone reading this comments section): http://ringomok.com/mathematics/combinatorics/burnsides-lemma/

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad the suggestion was helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Remark.** I somehow missed the fact that this is a duplicate question.
This is the [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53859/)
to the original computation, which did not include the PIE component.

The number of different isomers can be calculated by an application of
the Polya Enumeration Theorem (PET) to the vertex permutation group of
the regular  icosahedron. We  will not be  concerned with  the central
vertex as it is  fixed by all rotations and only adds  a factor of two
to  the result.  The general  case  that includes  reflections can  be
challenging and may require assistance  from a computer algebra system
but rotations only are just simple  enough that they can be done using
pen  and paper  and  your  imagination (it seems difficult to mentally
reflect an  icosahedron through  its center  and factor  the resulting
permutation).

We will now  compute the cycle index $Z(Q)$ of  the vertex permutation
group $Q$ of the regular icosahedron in order to apply PET. As this is
the dual of the regular  dodecahedron and the dodecahedron is somewhat
simpler to  work with we will  use the dodecahedron and  calculate the
face permutation group of the  regular dodecahedron, which can be seen
at this [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron).

We enumerate  the permutations in  this group. There is  the identity,
which contributes $$a_1^{12}.$$ There are  two rotations about an axis
passing  through any  one of  ten  pairs of  opposite vertices,  which
contributes $$10\times 2\times a_3^4.$$ There are four rotations about
an  axis passing  through  the centers  of  any one  of  six pairs  of
opposite  faces,  for  a contribution  of  $$6\times  4\times  a_1^2
a_5^2.$$ Finally there is a rotation about an axis passing through the
centers  of  any  one  of  fifteen pairs  of  opposite  edges,  for  a
contribution of $$15\times a_2^6.$$

This gives the following cycle index:
$$Z(Q)
= \frac{1}{60} 
\left(a_1^{12} + 20a_3^4 + 24 a_1^2 a_5^2 + 15 a_2^6\right).$$

which in turn  gives the  following generating  function for  two colors  / two types of atoms:
$${\frac { \left( 1+z \right) ^{12}}{60}}+1/4\, 
\left( {z}^{2}+1 \right) ^{6}+2/5\, \left( 1+z
 \right) ^{2} \left( {z}^{5}+1 \right) ^{2}
+1/3\, \left( {z}^{3}+1 \right) ^{4}$$
or alternatively 
$${z}^{12}+{z}^{11}+3\,{z}^{10}+5\,{z}^{9}+12\,{z}^{8}+14\,{z}^{7}
\\+24\,{z}^{6}+14\,{z}^{5}+12\,{z}^{4}+5\,{z}^{3}+3\,{z}^{2}+z+1.$$

This is indexed by the number of instances of the one type of atom.
Answering the OPs question, if you put a silver atom in the center that leaves four silver, eight gold, and the generating function says that there are $12$ isomers. If you put a gold atom in the center that leaves five silver and seven gold and the generating function says there are $14$ isomers.

With $N$ different colors we obtain the sequence
$$1, 96, 9099, 280832, 4073375, 36292320, 230719293, 
\\ 1145393152, 4707296613, 16666924000,\ldots$$

which points us to [OEIS A000545](https://oeis.org/A000545) 
where the above calculation is confirmed.

Note that we can derive a formula for the case of $N$ colors
by using the fact that it is given by
$$Z(Q)(C_1+C_2+\cdots+C_N)_{C_1=1, C_2=1, \ldots C_N=1}.$$
This yields
$$a_N = \frac{1}{60} 
\left(N^{12} + 44N^4 + 15 N^6\right).$$

The sequence $\{a_N\}$ counts colorings using  at most $N$ colors and we
need  to use  the principle  of inclusion-exclusion  (PIE) to  get the
number  of  colorings with  exactly  $M$  colors, call  this  sequence
$\{b_M\}.$

We have
$$b_M = \sum_{N=1}^M {M\choose N} (-1)^{M-N} a_N.$$
This gives the sequence
$$1, 94, 8814, 245008, 2759250, 15884004, 52701264, 106866144, \\
134719200, 103118400, 43908480, 7983360, 0, 0, 0, 0,\ldots$$
which is finite  because there are only twelve  vertices available for
coloring and hence no coloring with thirteen different colors, etc.

Observe that
$$\frac{12!}{60} = 7983360$$
which is because with twelve different colors all orbits have the same size, namely $60.$

This list at [MSE Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) has many more Polya / Burnside computations by various users.

Comment: What we have here matches the data at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyhedronColoring.html) which is linked to from the OEIS entry.

Comment: That's what it means. And using **exactly** two colors as opposed to **at most two colors** there are $94$ colorings ($96$ colorings minus two monocrome colorings).