# Jumping tools in a lattice

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, coloring

a 7 * 7 lattice. In the inner area of the frame of the lattice is a structure of 3 * 3 size of 9 tools placed on the lattice points. When there are three adjacent lattice points, either horizontally or vertically, two adjacent tools , and the third is free (without tool), one tool can be jumped over the other, linearly, into the free point, and the other tool is removed. it is impossible to leave one tool in the board , how we can prove it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgJhG.jpg)

Comment: !!? if somthing is not clear ask me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coloring dodecahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53859/coloring-dodecahedron)

Answer (score 1):

The move you want is impossible.

On each lattice point, assign it to an integral coordinate. On any specific time, we can define the following sets:

$$
\begin{aligned}
T &:= \{(x,y) \ | \ (x,y) \text{ has a tool on it}\}\\
S_0 &:= \{(x, y) \in T \ | \ x + y \equiv 0 \pmod 3\}\\
S_1 &:= \{(x, y) \in T \ | \ x + y \equiv 1 \pmod 3\}\\
S_2 &:= \{(x, y) \in T \ | \ x + y \equiv 2 \pmod 3\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

and let $(n_0, n_1, n_2) := (|S_0|\pmod 2, |S_1|\pmod 2, |S_2|\pmod 2)$. At the beginning, $(n_0, n_1, n_2) := (1,1,1)$. After each valid step, two of $S_i$ got one element removed, while the third got one element inserted, so after each step $(n_0, n_1, n_2)$ is either $(0,0,0)$ or $(1,1,1)$.

So there is no chance that exactly one tool remains.

Comment: can you explain more? what it is mean (x,y) has a tool on it?

Comment: I just mean $T$ is the coordinates your tools lie on.

Comment: please can you explain it (n0,n1,n2):=(|S0|(mod2),|S1|(mod2),|S2|(mod2)) . what is n0 , n1 , n2 ??

Comment: If you have a hard time understand things written down in formal math notations, think of it this way: On the lattice, draw diagonal lines of the form $x+y = n, n \in \mathbb Z$. Color the grids alternatively in red, green, blue, red, green, blue, ..., base on the diagonal line it lies on. Initially 3 tools each lies on red, green, and blue grid points. Try to track how many grids of each color the tools lie on after each valid step.

Comment: Can you please attach a photo of the solution? I have an exam tomorrow and Ihave to understand it please. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly easy programming exercise to enumerate all configurations that can occur after a certain number of moves.  There are none that end with one tool after $8$ moves.